# How to use while and when in one sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

> 1. When a traffic light changes to yellow, while approaching an
>      intersection, you should slow down.
> 2. While approaching an intersection, when a traffic light changes to yellow,
>      intersection, you should slow down.

I want to use "while" and "when" in one sentence, but am not sure which of the two sentences above I created is better.

Comment: When a traffic light changes to yellow, you should slow down while approaching an intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the punctuation and grammar to use either:

Original:

1. When a traffic light changes to yellow**<s>,</s>** while approaching an intersection, you should slow down.
2. While approaching an intersection**<s>,</s>** when a traffic light changes to yellow, <s>intersection,</s> you should slow down.

Corrected:

1. When a traffic light changes to yellow while approaching an intersection, you should slow down.
2. While approaching an intersection when a traffic light changes to yellow, you should slow down.